# GWT MVP: HandlerManager EventHandler vs GUI EventHandler

Tags: java, events, gwt, gwt-mvp

I am using GWT MVP to develop an application. I saw we can have two kinds of event handlers in GWT MVP code, but I am not very sure about which kind should I use in which place:

1) HandlerManager (eventBus) EventHandlers (e.g. `EditEventHandler` below) in `AppController`:

```
eventBus.addHandler(EditEvent.TYPE,
      new EditEventHandler() {
        public void onEdit(EditEvent event) {
          doEdit(event.getId()); // this would open a new screen, call AsyncService etc
        }
      });
```

I understand, these kind of event handlers are used for handling application-wide custom events.

2) GUI/View Event Handlers (e.g. `ClickHandler`) in `Presenter`, where I handle the GUI event and then fire the application event to invoke its handler as below:

```
display.getList().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      int selectedRow = display.getClickedRow(event);

      if (selectedRow >= 0) {
        String id = myDetails.get(selectedRow).getId();
        eventBus.fireEvent(new EditEvent(id)); // this in turn would invoke the EditEventHandler above
      }
    }
  });
```

Now, my questions are:

1) Why do we need to write EventHandler for application events (e.g. `EditEvent`), and not add that code directly in the associated GUI event handler (e.g. `addClickHandler`)?

2)Can't we write the code for opening new screen, calling AsyncService etc directly in GUI EventHandler method, such as `onClick` ?

3) Wouldn't that make your code more readable, as the event that is triggered and the work that needs to be done is all in one place i.e.`Presenter` and you don't have to go back and forth between your `Presenter` code and `AppController` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could do that and in a small applications this might probably be the right approach. However you will definately increase coupling between your GUI, business logic and the various components. You should envision your screens as independent units and avoid any coupling between those units. In the best case your screen which displays a list of records should know nothing about the other screens or any other components. It should only care about those records.
2. Technically there is no reason why you can't call `AsyncService` in your GUI EventHandler. Just make sure you do it in your `Presenter` and not in your `View`. However the more complex your app gets the messier this approach might get. You will have many AsyncService calls sprinkled all over your various `Presenters`. It might be a better approach to group them in your  `AppController` so there is 1.) one place to look for and 2.) you can easily test/mock all `AsyncService` calls in your `AppController`.
3. Work that can be done inside a `Presenter` should also be done there without needing to go through `AppController` and back. However it still might make sense to put the `AsyncService` calls into your `AppController` because you might need to do some bookeeping (for example caching the results in `LocalStroage`, submitting other Events, etc) and/or notify other screens/components about the loaded data.

Think of Events as messages. Here is an example:
You have a View/Presenter pair for displaying a list of records (i.e. `RecordListPresenter`). The user clicks on the edit button on one of the records and you have a separate View/Presenter pair for editing the specific record (i.e `RecordEditPresenter`). Instead of having a reference from your `RecordListPresenter` to your `RecordEditPresenter` which would make them aware of each other and increase the coupling the `RecordListPresenter` sends a message to edit a record (`Edit` event). The `AppController` will act as a [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) and open load the data and open the `RecordEditEditor` (it can also only fire an Event with the loaded data and the `RecordEditEditor` could reveal itself).
But now imagine that you also have a `HeaderPresenter` for displaying some breadcrumb information (like which record it is editing). If you go the "eventless" approach you would need another reference in the `RecordListPresenter` and `RecordEditPresenter` to it to drive it. With `Events` those `Presenters` don't have to know that there is a `HeaderPresenter`. They just fire Events.

Now in a complex app you might have many of those independend units.

Comment: so as a rule of thumb, we should use event messages (e.g. `Edit` event), when one presenter wants to invoke another presenter, so that presenters remain decoupled from each other. Is there any other scenario where these `event messages` should be preferred over writing the code in GUI event handlers?

Comment: Well it applies to everything where you might need to notify multiple components (doesn't have to be `Presenters` ) about some interesting change. GUI event handler should only contain things that are relevant just in the context of that `View`/`Presenter`